# Windows 11 and 10 Unable to boot on x570 Motherboard. Not even USB's

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11, amd-ryzen

I have been through the run around trying to get my computer to boot after a 2 second blackout from a car hitting a telephone pole near me. I first started with attempting to load into the windows repair menu but after its says attempting to repair this computer, it throws me into a back screen with my only my cursor visible. I then restart a couple times only to get an infinite windows loading circle.

I then decided to attempt booting off windows 10 and 11 USB's but they all brought me to a blank purplish blue screen (same color as the windows install screen) I even tried Hirens boot CD. I then decided to try a couple flavors of Linux (ubuntu and kali) They worked great! no problems as far as I could tell...

This led me to believe there may be a problem with the BIOS, so I went through and cleared the CMOS and loaded into the BIOS. Here is the check list of everything important I checked.

---

- BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode = UEFI
- Secure Boot = Enabled
- Secure Boot Mode = Standard
- Security Device Support = Enabled
- Disable Block Sid = Disabled
- AMD fTPM switch = AMD CPU fTPM Disabled
- Device Select = TPM 2.0

---

This only throws me back into the infinite loading screen.

I then re-flash the BIOS with the latest version (same as what was already on there). I get the same result with factory settings and the settings set to what they are above.

This then made me think that maybe my drive is bad so I pulled out the m.2 and slotted it into my extra pc I keep in the closet. Bam!! loaded right into windows repair menu no problem. I then ran the following commands in cmd.

---

- BOOTREC /FIXMBR (it worked)
- BOOTREC /FIXBOOT (access restricted / read only)
- BOOTREC /RebuildBCD (access restricted / read only)

---

I then just closed out of cmd and tried booting into windows through the repair screen. IT worked flawlessly and I even logged in and checked some of my files. After a couple of perfect restarts (no problems or repair screen). I decided to slot it back into my main rig...

Right back where we started...

I even slotted the m.2 from the old machine into the main rig and still the same problem.

This had made the think that maybe it is my motherboard, I'm not to sure if TPM has anything to do with this but I'm pulling my hair out as I do my work and school on this computer. If I have missed anything glaringly obvious please let me know I will list the specs of the computer below. I'll also post pictures at your request.

- CPU: Ryzen 5800X
- MOBO: MPG X570 Gaming Edge Wifi
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 3200mhz
- M.2: WD Black Sn850 1TB
- GPU: EVGA GTX 1080ti

Comment: While TPM 2.0 support is not required for Windows 10 it is required for Windows 11, so it’s unlikely to be the reason, your unable to boot into Windows 10. Besides your CPU supports fTPM

Comment: yes and id like to add that windows 11 is what the main rig was running during the outage. and yes I did try booting with fTPM instead of the other option and same result.

Comment: My point, your problem, isn’t connected to TPM.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it looks like the root cause was a faulty SSD, After leaving the windows infinite loading screen on for 2+ hours it finally kicked into windows (all be it very very slow) After opening up task manager I noticed that my ssd D: drive was completely saturated despite being inaccessible and in the RAW format. It looks like the power outage completely broke the drive, I have tried reformatting though GUI and CMD but nothing plus multiple data recovery apps wouldn't do the trick either. So I believe it is a full loss.

It just boggles me that windows would be almost un usable when a drive that doesn't host the OS decided to "kapoot". Not to mention that it even prevented bootable USB's with windows from loading...

Anyways hope someone finds this in the future when they are experiencing this strange issue.

Comment: "After leaving the windows infinite loading screen on for 2+ hours... I noticed that my ssd D: drive was completely saturated." SSD's have a limited write lifetime. This is the third post I've seen recently where the SSD died after long-running Windows "repair". It would seem it is safer for an SSD to be restored from a previous image than to try a long Windows disk repair.

Comment: Well my theory is the drive was corrupted during the power outage. Then the drive got put into a mode that had it constantly spitting out data. and I'm assuming it saturated the data lanes and caused problems. still not sure why it wouldn't let me boot windows from a USB, i can do it now so im at a loss for what was happening.